# Mathematica closes after initerlising internal preferences

Tags: ubuntu

I have just installed Mathematica, and when I try to open it it closes after internalising internal preferences.
I use mathematica 10.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Could you please copy here the exact error message?

Comment: What do you mean by "internalising internal preferences?"